# Sublime 3 multiple replace spaces with underscores

Tags: regex, sublimetext

In my html page I have a lot of strings inside tags.
like

```
<p>Some string 1</p>
<p>Some string 2</p>
<p>Any string 3</p>
```

I need to put all of them to attribute TRANSLATE, lowercase them and replace all spaces to underscores inside strings.

So I multiselect all of them with holded CTRL, then ctrl+K, ctrl+L make them lowercase, CTRL+x - erase, two left arrows for going inside tags, write translate="PASTE HERE"

Now I have

```
<p translate="some string 1"></p>
<p translate="some string 2"></p>
<p translate="any string 3"></p>
```

Next step - I need to make underscores instead of spaces.

To find all translate strings I use regex (?s)translate=".+?"
But how to replace? Help.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404156/sublime-text-2-how-do-i-replace-text-in-a-selection)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `ctrl + H` and then

Use negative-lookbehind to search spaces which are not preceded by `p`.

```
(?<!p)\h+
```

`\h` matches only horizontal spaces.

Now `replace-all` it with `_`.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple but will work and faster than looking for a smarter answer.

Find this: `translate="(.*) (.*)"`

Replace with this: `translate="\1_\2"`

Keep using `Replace All` until all your unwanted spaces are underscores (in the example you gave, twice).

Comment: Only last space replaces with underscore

Comment: What does that mean? Did you not keep using `Replace All` until all spaces covered as per my advice? Or are you trying to say something else?